# Need a clarification on if condition with and operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please correct me if i am wrong:

```
a = "Disabled"

if a == "Disabled" and "Disable":
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

if a is "Disabled" or "Disable"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wanted to write is

```
if a == "Disabled" or a == "Disable":
```

Other option is

```
if a in ("Disabled", "Disable):
```

Comment: Thanks, its working :)